# Storing leading zeros of integers in MySQL database as INTEGER

Tags: php, mysql, string, integer, varchar

I need MySQL to store numbers in a integer field and maintain leading zeros. I cannot use the zerofill option as my current field is Bigint(16) and numbers can vary in amount of leading zeros. IE: 0001 - 0005, then 008 - 010 may need to be stored. I am not concerned about uniqueness of numbers (these aren't being used as IDs or anything) but I still need them to be stored preferably as INTS.

The issue using CHAR/VARCHAR and then typecasting the values as integers in PHP means that sorting results via queries leads to alphanumeric sorting, IE: SORT BY number ASC would produce

```
001
002
003
1
100
101
102
2
```

Clearly not in numerical order, but in alphanumeric order, which isn't wanted.

Hoping for some clever workarounds :)

Comment: integers don't *have* leading zeroes. Only string representations of them can. So if you "need" leading zeroes, you'll have to store a string representation. Why can't you do this kind of formatting at display time, rather than putting it in the database?

Comment: 1 and 001 and different values. But as int they are the same: how should these be sorted and compared? as int or as varchar?

Answer (score 24):

Keep the numbers stored as integers.

Then use function [**`LPAD()`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) to show the numbers (left) padded with zeros:

```
SELECT LPAD( 14, 7, '0') AS padded;

| padded  |
-----------
| 0000014 |
```

If the number of zerofill characters is variable, add another column in the table with that (zerofill) length.

Comment: Even when I can confirm that your query works, I have a doubt, Does exist an impact about performance when `lpad` is used for numeric types? It because `lpad` is a `string-function`. Consider the scenario about having a query retrieving a lot of records and `ldap` is used to format the output of a numeric type.

Answer (score 8):

Change the structure of the field and make the Attributes `UNSIGNED_ZEROFILL` to keep the zeros.

But you should be careful to the Length of the field, because it's gonna return all the rest numbers to zeros so put the length of your field

Answer (score 7):

You can still sort the string(CHAR/VARCHAR) columns like integer using [CAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

```
ORDER BY CAST(`col_name` AS SIGNED) DESC
```

So, you can store them in CHAR/ VARCHAR type fields.

Comment: Could also do `ORDER BY col_name + 0 DESC` to sort a varchar like integer

Comment: That doesn't actually work.

Castign to integer makes 001 and 1 the same.

The OP actualyl wants to put 

1

before 
001

you need to REVERSE the data, then ascii sort it, then reverse it again!

Answer (score 6):

You can not store integer with leading zeroes. One way is keeping it in varchar as well as int columns. In this case, you need two columns, one value and the other intValue and while sorting, you can use the intValue for sorting. This is easy to implement.

```
Select Value from Table order by intValue;
```

The other option can be using two columns, one valu and othe NumOfZero and use these for the desired results. This is complex, but might be light on the DB.

Comment: Note: if you know that the column will always be the same length, use CHAR, not VARCHAR.

Comment: Using the int value for sorting is incorrect., because it will collapse 1 and 01 and 001 all to 1.  using NumOfZero is also insufficient to allow a proper sort.

The correct solution is to store as char, and then left pad with SPACES up to the width of the char field.  this will make an ascii sort work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, nobody has this right.

You cant' store leading zeroes in an integer.  PERIOD. You must store as character.

For the case that the desired number of digits to use is known, you can simply do something like

SELECT (LPAD(zip,5,0))

to put the zeroes back.

But if you have variable numbers of digits, AND variable numbers of leading zeroes. you can't just cast to integer and sort, because that will fold 1 and 01 an d001 and 0001 into each other, and return them in the order they were already in the database.  which is wrong.

But if you sort as character without the cast, the field gets compared left to right, when you need to compare right to left to properly sort it.

The ONLY way to sort in the right order is to left pad with spaces, either as it gets into the database, or with LPAD() function.

ORDER BY LPAD(number,16," ") will return data in the proper order.