# phpmyadmin wrong number ordering

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, numbers

Might be a silly question,

but if I want to order by a field called `CODE`, then it orders like this:

```
1, 101, 102, 1010, 2, 201, 2003
```

and I'd like to order them like:

```
1, 2, 101, 102, 201, 1010, 2003
```

the code field is: *VAR(4)*. (Var, because INT cuts off the zero as beginning number, which makes 0110 to 110, and that's no good.) and I'm ordering with: `ORDER BY code ASC`.

Answer (score 1):

if your data type for code is varchar and u order the data by using: "order by code asc", the order of your data will based on ASCII. Try to use: "order by length(code), code"

Comment: I see now. After 999 comes 0111. Is there a way to get this after the 0?

Comment: Actually i don't know about that. i've no idea for now. But why don't you simply make all the code become 4 digits. So, your 999 become 0999, then 1 become 0001, and so on.

Comment: it's too late for that, the items in this company are already numbered like that ^^ .. unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CODE FROM tableName ORDER BY CONVERT(INT,CODE) ASC;
```

Comment: still, check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'code) ASC LIMIT 0, 20' at line 6.



[CODE]
("
    SELECT *
    FROM item
     INNER JOIN itemgroup on item.itemgroupid = itemgroup.itemgroupid 
     INNER JOIN status on status.statusid = item.status
     INNER JOIN owner on owner.ownerid = item.owner
    ORDER BY CONVERT(int, code)
    ASC LIMIT $startpoint, $limit");
[CODE]

Comment: The cast I don't understand, since numbers look like they are ordered randomly. Still syntax error for CONVERT, but I think it has to be placed in the SELECT clause. Still, converting to INT will replace the codes like 0111, 0231, 0021 by 111, 231 and 21.

Comment: check these posts, if they help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686849/sorting-varchar-field-numerically-in-mysql, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873354/storing-leading-zeros-of-integers-in-mysql-database-as-integer..also, imho, numbers shouldn't be saved as strings..