# PHP MySQL Convert to SMALLINT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My apologies if this has already been answered, I used the search function and could not find a question which matched this exactly.

I am trying to insert a postcode field (Australian) into my database via mysql_query, I have confirmed that everything works, however a valid postcode could be, for example 0021 or 0214.

The problem is, that it is automatically discarding the leading zero's when inserting into the database which is obviously problematic, if memory serves me this could be because the integer is unsigned?

I need the value to be of the SMALLINT type, and retain the leading zeros, I understand that mySQL has a CONVERT function, however I never could get it to work.

This is my current insert query:

```
$insertquery = "INSERT IGNORE INTO user (username, password, firstname, surname, address, state, postcode)
                VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$fname', '$surname', '$address', '$state', '$postcode')";
$insertresult = mysql_query($insertquery);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing leading zeros of integers in MySQL database as INTEGER](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873354/storing-leading-zeros-of-integers-in-mysql-database-as-integer)

Comment: @mieko it looks the same , but its not a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The removal of leading zeroes is not because of an `integer` being `signed` or `small`. It has to do with the fact that it is an `integer` all-together. If you want to retain leading zeroes, you will need to convert to using `VARCHAR`, or you will have to use `lpad()` when fetching the postcodes.

In my opinion, just go with `VARCHAR`.

**edit** : Please read Leonardo Phinheiro's answer for an alternative! As he says, you can set your integer to `ZEROFILL`. Though I would still use `VARCHAR` for something like postcodes. Here in The Netherlands we even have letters in our postcodes.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, my coworker requested SMALLINT however I will explain that multiple Australian postcodes start with 0's.
So how would I go about implementing that into my query?

Comment: @user3577618 Which solution would you like to implement? `smallint with lpad()` , `Smallint with zerofill` or `varchar` ?

Comment: smallint with lpad() looks to me like the most viable option.
So for instance if you padded it to a length of 4, and a user entered 0023. It will convert from 23 to 0023?

Comment: @user3577618 Ok, for implementation, when you are doing your `select` statements, do them like this: `select lpad(postcode,4,'0') from myTable`. My advice is go with `VARCHAR`, or else use `ZEROFILL` so you don't have to adjust your queries.

Comment: Where would I put that select statement though?

I'm selecting everything from the registration form and inserting into the database (it's hosted on a server), so the select statement is "SELECT * FROM user";

I don't want to modify the actual postcode database field itself, just modify the way that the user entered postcode variable is stored, will the lpad function store it as a SMALLINT?

Comment: @user3577618 If you really don't want to alter the table, then your query will be like: `select *, lpad(postcode,4,'0') as padded_postcode from user;`

Comment: @user3577618 To change the table just execute the `Alter` statement directly to Mysql. You don't have to do that in PHP. This is something you only do once. So fire it in your command prompt, in your Mysql Workbench or in you PhpMyAdmin

Comment: I'm just using PHP code and the mysql_query command, I'm not actually using any MYSQL server-related applications, just Notepad++.
I did this: 
$changequery = "ALTER TABLE users
                CHANGE postcode SMALLINT(4) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT          NULL"; however it still does not work.

Comment: @user3577618 and dont forget to do: `mysql_query($changequery) or die("error: " . mysql_error());`

Comment: Solved it, thanks so much nl-x. I discovered that it wasn't working properly because one of the entries had a blank value in the postcode field, so obviously it couldn't truncate it properly.

Answer (score 1):

change data type to **unsigned-zerofill** whatever you are using, float, int, smallint... only edit the field to **unsigned-zerofill**

Comment: Well spotted! Never used this before

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain leading zeros you should consider changing type of the postcode to `varchar`.
Execute following SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE user MODIFY postcode VARCHAR(8);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't store an integer with leading zeros inherently in MySQL. However, you can use both MySQL and PHP to generate the leading zeros every time.

Check `LPAD()` in MySQL:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad

And `str_pad()` in PHP:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php