# php code generation from 00001 to 99999 for any particular month

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this php code to generate a code

```
<?php 
$year = date('y'); //gets 2 digits of year, ex, year 2014 as 14
$month = date('m');//gets 2 digits of month, ex, month July as 07
$day = date('d');//gets 2 digits of date, ex, date 07
$random = substr( md5(rand()), 0, 4); //generate 4 digits random number using 0-9 and a-z
$code = $year . $month . $day . $random;
echo $code;
?>
```

Next I am trying to add a 5 digit number to this code starting from 00001 to 99999

means the code shall look like, YYMMDDXXXXNNNNN while I have achieved YYMMDDXXXX, I am still struggling with NNNNN part (00000-99999).

How can that be made and concatenated to this variable $code with each user generate entry.

I want to mention here, this is the code number of a form, when 1st user fills the form on any date the NNNNN given to him would be 00001, for 2nd user 00002, 3rd user 00003 and so on, irrespective of any date in a particular month.

Also, When the month is changed from current to next, I want that NNNNN again to be reset to 00001.

How can I achieve those two things.

Any idea guys?

here is the snippet
http://codepad.org/cgPLEtr7

Comment: You need to store the previously allocated value of NNNNN. Then retrieve it and if the same month add one to it. Problem is the value might change between you retrieving it and assigning the updated value to a record.

Comment: @Kickstart that would be 2nd part. First, how to generate this?

Comment: You will require to persist the counter and month in server or database. Once month changes reset the counter.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao can you show how to achieve that?

Comment: Generating a single random number is easy ( `SUBSTR("00000".RAND(0,99999), -4)` ), but that number could have been allocated already

Comment: @Kickstart I don't want to add a random number. when 1st user fills the form on any date the NNNNN given to him would be 00001, for 2nd user 00002, 3rd user 00003 and so on, irrespective of any date in a particular month.

Comment: As my original comment says, you need to store it. If one not found already you start at 00001, otherwise you use the max value, add one, store it and use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$form = sprintf("%05s", 1);
$code = $year . $month . $day . $random . $form;
```

to get the value of `$code` right.

Below are a few more hints about your 'other' queries.

You could try setting up another MySQL table to store your 5-digit form number, which will initially be '00000', as a `varchar`.

Then, on data `insert` to your original table, trigger MySQL to update this value by +1 after a `cast`, as in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6873429/3318560

Draw this value to your form via PHP, and keep it there as a hidden value that you will append to your `$code`.

Finally, you could use a MySQL event to reset your value to `00000` each month.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create a table to store the counters in:-

```
CREATE TABLE month_counter
(
    id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    aMonth CHAR(6),
    aCounter INT ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `aMonth` (`aMonth`)
);
```

Then when you want a new value use:-

```
INSERT INTO month_counter (id, aMonth, aCounter)
VALUES(NULL, '201407', 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), aCounter=aCounter+1
```

When you execute that query from php you can use LAST_INSERT_ID() to get the id of the last inserted row, which you can then select the value from:-

```
$sql = "SELECT aCounter FROM month_counter WHERE id = ".LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Note that the value could change between the INSERT and the SELECT, hence you should wrap this up in a transaction